# What's the difference between true statements and real information?

Tags: truth, semantics, philosophy-of-law

In Sweden we have legislation about

1. "Osant intygande" - "Untrue verification" e.g. false and fabricated Ph D diploma or similar
2. "Oriktig uppgift" - "Not a real piece of information" e.g. registrering with the authorities that your address is somewhere else than you actually reside

How can I know which is which?

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit more? What is "real" information? The term "real" isn't often used in philosophy in my experience; most people stick with statements either being "true" or "false", rather than "real" or "unreal". Also, fabricating information (lying) is a separate complexity beause something can be a lie yet true at the same time, because a lie is simply a belief of a condition. For example: For me to say, "My sister is pregnant" would be in my mind a lie, but I haven't seen her recently, she may in fact be pregnant now and not have told me. The lie could thus be true.

Comment: I thought that "real" information is something like "I live in Stockholm, Sweden" where "true" is something like "If you go outdoors in the winter it will be cold." I'm trying to understand which is which when neither is allowed. ("oriktig" = not real, "osann" = untrue)

Comment: This is a translation, and I suppose a bad one, of Swedish law terms. It has nothing to do with philosophy, but it is a question about Swedish law.

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Swedish, translating "Oriktig uppgift" as "not a real piece of information" seems very, very dubious. I'd translate it as "making a false statement". And "Osant intygande" seems to be "misrepresentation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat speculative, but (2) seems to be just lying (to the authorities), while (1) is submitting a false piece of physical evidence or a false document. The associated claim may actually be true, e.g. you really do have a PhD, but you present a false PhD diploma. This would make you guilty of (1) but not of (2). While if you just lie, without presenting physical evidence or documents, you will be guilty of (2) but not of (1).